# What is Angular Animation Version that supports to Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-animations

I am new to Angular, So I need to know what is the suitable Angular Animation that works with Angular 5. And how I install it. Because latest version has mismatches with the Angular 5.

Or I can't figure out what the error is.

```
ERROR TypeError: _this._driver.validateStyleProperty is not a function
at eval (browser.js:874)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at eval (browser.js:873)
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor._validateStyleAst (browser.js:870)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.visitStyle (browser.js:810)
at visitDslNode (browser.js:515)
at AnimationAstBuilderVisitor.visitQuery (browser.js:987)
at visitDslNode (browser.js:523)
at eval (browser.js:755)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, Finally I have founded the answer. This error is resolved after roll-backing the Angular Animation Version 5.2.11 using this command

```
npm install @angular/animations@5.2.11
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/animations

It might be because it did not install correctly